# Limit of partial sums where summands also depend on limit index

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_i, a_i^n \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}, i, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i$ exists and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_i^n = a_i$ for all $i$.

I would like to prove
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i^n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty a_i. \tag{*}$$

However, this is not true without further assumptions (consider $a_i^n := \max\{0, 2i-n\}$).

The summands I have in mind are $a_i^n = \frac{n-|i|}{n}a_i$.

What assumptions do I need for (*) to be true?

Edit: I realized that I want to prove something slightly more general: I don't want to assume that the summands are non-negative. However, the sums can be assumed to be absolutely summable and $|a_i^n| \leq |a_i|$.

Comment: You can use the monotone convergence theorem, which also holds for series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Monotone convergence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) and the  [Dominated convergence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Moreover you can basically use any theorem that holds for the Lebesgue integral because (in some cases) the series itself is a Lebesgue integral.

In particular this theorem holds

> Let $\# \; : \; \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to [0,\infty]$ be defined in the following way:
> $$\#(A) := \begin{cases} card(A) &\text{ if } A \text{ is finite } \\
>  \infty &\text{ if } A \text{ is infinite} \end{cases}$$
>
> Let $(a_i)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Then the sequence is itself a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and its Lebesgue integral is well-defined:
>
> $$\int_{\mathbb{N}}{a_i d\#}$$
>
> Also, the integral exists and it's finite if and only if $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{|a_i|} < \infty$ and moreover:
>
> $$\int_{\mathbb{N}}{a_i d\#} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{ a_i }$$

$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

This theorem allows you to to use any theorem about the Lebesgue integral for series.

Also sometimes you can do some tricks with $\limsup$ and $\liminf$

Comment: Good idea using the counting measure. However, I'm still not sure how to prove my exact statement using these theorems as they both consider sums/integrals over a fixed set. However, in my case, the set ($\{1, ..., n\}$ changes with the limit index.

Comment: You just let $a^n_{n+1} = a^n_{n+2} = \dots = 0$ and then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{a^n_k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a^n_k} = \int_{\mathbb{N}}{a^n_i d\#}$

Comment: Using dominated convergence theorem you get that the statement is true if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{|a_k|} < +\infty$